# Como modificar una propiedad la función data() del componente padre, vuejs2?

Tags: vue.js

De esta forma tengo el componente principal "App.vue"

```
<template>
    <v-app>
        <v-navigation-drawer fixed :mini-variant="miniVariant" :clipped="clipped" v-model="drawer" app>
            <v-list>
                <v-list-tile value="true" v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i" @click="linkto(item.linkpath)">
                    <v-list-tile-action>
                        <v-icon v-html="item.icon"></v-icon>
                    </v-list-tile-action>
                    <v-list-tile-content>
                        <v-list-tile-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
                    </v-list-tile-content>
                </v-list-tile>
            </v-list>
        </v-navigation-drawer>
        <v-toolbar fixed app :clipped-left="clipped" v-if="menuSuperior">
            <v-toolbar-side-icon @click.stop="drawer = !drawer"></v-toolbar-side-icon>
            <v-btn icon @click.stop="miniVariant = !miniVariant">
                <v-icon v-html="miniVariant ? 'chevron_right' : 'chevron_left'"></v-icon>
            </v-btn>
            <v-toolbar-title v-text="title"></v-toolbar-title>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-btn icon @click.stop="rightDrawer = !rightDrawer">
                <v-icon>menu</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
        </v-toolbar>
        <v-content>
            <router-view></router-view>
        </v-content>
        <v-navigation-drawer temporary :right="right" v-model="rightDrawer" fixed>
            <v-list>
                <v-list-tile @click.native="right = !right">
                    <v-list-tile-action>
                        <v-icon>compare_arrows</v-icon>
                    </v-list-tile-action>
                    <v-list-tile-title>Switch drawer (click me)</v-list-tile-title>
                </v-list-tile>
            </v-list>
        </v-navigation-drawer>
        <v-footer :fixed="fixed" app>
            <span>&copy; 2019</span>
        </v-footer>
    </v-app>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            clipped: false,
            menuSuperior: true,
            drawer: false,
            fixed: false,
            items: [
                { icon: 'home', title: 'Home', linkpath: '/home' },
                { icon: 'star', title: 'Hola Vue', linkpath: '/helloworld' },
                { icon: 'people', title: 'Usuarios', linkpath: '/usuarios' }
            ],
            miniVariant: false,
            right: true,
            rightDrawer: false,
            title: 'Aplicacion'
        }
    },
    methods: {
        linkto(pathname) {
            this.$router.push({ path: pathname })
        },
    }
}

</script>
```

En el cual se cargan las rutas, como veran existe una propiedad en el modelo llamado `menuSuperior:true`,
En la parte de `<router-view></router-view>` al iniciar la aplicacion, cargo el login, es el siguiente componente:

```
<template>
    <v-app id="inspire">
      <v-content>
        <v-container fluid fill-height>
          <v-layout align-center justify-center>
            <v-flex xs12 sm8 md4>
              <v-card class="elevation-12">
                <v-toolbar dark color="primary">
                  <v-toolbar-title>Iniciar sesión</v-toolbar-title>
                  <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                </v-toolbar>
                <v-card-text>
                  <v-form>
                    <v-text-field prepend-icon="person" name="login" label="Correo" type="text" v-model="email"></v-text-field>
                    <v-text-field prepend-icon="lock" name="password" label="Contraseña" id="password" type="password" v-model="password"></v-text-field>
                  </v-form>
                </v-card-text>
                <v-card-actions>
                  <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                  <v-btn color="primary" @click="validate">Iniciar sesión</v-btn>
                </v-card-actions>
                <v-card-actions>
                    <v-btn fab dark small color="primary" @click="loginGoogle">
                      <v-icon dark>g_translate</v-icon>
                    </v-btn>
                    <v-btn fab dark small color="primary" @click="loginFacebook">
                      <v-icon dark>thumb_up</v-icon>
                    </v-btn>
                    <div>
                    </div>
                </v-card-actions>
              </v-card>
            </v-flex>
          </v-layout>
        </v-container>
      </v-content>
  </v-app>
</template>
<script>
import firebase from 'firebase'

export default {
    data: () => ({
      valid: true,
      password: '',
      passwordRules: [
        v => !!v || 'Contraseña es requerida'
      ],
      email: '',
      emailRules: [
        v => !!v || 'E-mail es requerido',
        v => /.+@.+/.test(v) || 'El email debe ser válido'
      ]
    })
  }
</script>
<style>
</style>
```

El detalle que al cargar el login se ve en la parte frontal el `v-toolbar`.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces como podria modificar la propiedad `menuSuperior` desde el componente del login, de tal forma que al cambiar el valor de esta propiedad a   `menuSuperior: false,` estaría ocultando el `v-toolbar` y quedando de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

o alguna otra solucion.

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Hay muchas opciones.. o agregas el menu en cada router, o te ocupas de pasarle un evento al padre.. pero en este caso, quien es el padre??? porque el router no emite eventos al main, Lo otro es que uses un store.. igual en general el menu siempre se ve..

Comment: en este caso el componente padre seria App.vue

Comment: en realidad. ni... porque hay algo de fondo que se ocupa de poner al hijo ahi adentro y lo va cambiando.. el padre es app.vue.. pero no es el padre per se... o sea.. no le pasas parametros a cada componente que se arma ahi adentro... porque se supone que lo de afuera es solo un contenedor... con un store, lo solucionas muy simple...

Comment: perdon, soy nuevo en este tema de vuejs, si pudieras apoyarme gracias.